# How to Resolve webpack vulnerabilities for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am creating browser addon and for packaging I am using webpack. I have following dependencies which result in vulnerabilities.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "minify-html-webpack-plugin": "^0.0.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-webext-plugin": "github:rpl/webpack-webext-plugin"
},
```

When I say `npm i` or `npm audit`, I get a long message ending with

```
found 21 vulnerabilities (9 low, 8 moderate, 3 high, 1 critical)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

`npm audit fix` is not able to fix them. How do I remove these vulnerabilities?

Can anyone also explain what are these vulnerabilities? What is the harm if I continue building my project with these vulnerabilities?

Comment: you should run `npm audit` to check the modules with vulnerabilities first for more details.  Usually it just need to update certain modules to latest version and it will fix the vulnerabilities

Comment: Couldn't understand much from npm audit output. But run npm i --upgrade --- no luck

Answer (score 0):

`devDependencies` are not included in production build, so if the `vulnerabilities` are only in `devDependencies`, they can be ignored. Also, update all dependencies with `pnpm update --latest`.